# Updating an existing website. how?

Tags: web, updatepanel

If I have a website that runs in online, how do i update my website? I do not want any client to see the progress. Only the output.  Using c panel to edit my website.

Answer (score 0):

Make a note on your website saying website is down for upgrading/maintenance. Take it off internet. Work on your code duly, update and host it back.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the. htaccess to display maintenance mode then change to normal mode after making the changes

Comment: How do i configure it. Can you specify?